# Installing TortoiseSVN - why to close Firefox?

Tags: installer, browser, firefox, tortoise-svn

I just installed the latest TortoiseSVN Client (v1.7.8) for windows [from this mirror here](http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tortoisesvn/1.7.11/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.7.11.23600-win32-svn-1.7.8.msi). In the installer I was asked to close Firefox to proceed. Why so? It made me nervous - does TortoiseSVN have anything to do with a web browser that I am unaware of?

Comment: If Firefox had a lock on the c++ redistributable or on a guy library that they both use (xul) this would explain it.

Comment: it might add a link to the protocol for SVN into firefox so links clicked will be handled by tortoise instead of erroring

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN integrates into Windows shell, and applications that use the open/save dialog are an obstacle for the installer's intention to restart the shell.

There is nothing special about Firefox. The same can happen with Notepad.